# Deploy angular-universal to apache server (Angular 9)

Tags: angular, apache, ubuntu, angular-universal

After build and run angular universal locally, I am trying to deploy to apache server. I am moving dist folder to public html.

[image]

I run `node dist/server/main.js` and it starts on port localhost:4000, when I curl localhost:4000 I am getting the content.

> p.s. I have also install pm2, and when I try `pm2 start dist/server/main.js` starts the server but when I try to curl it shows *Internal server error*

I have edit also .conf file to proxy to localhost:4000:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
```

When I try to access it shows

[image]

vhost file

```
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain/public/dist/browser

    <Directory /var/www/domain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    <IfModule mod_dir.c>
        DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.html index.xhtml index.htm
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:4000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:4000/
```

Comment: Show your complete vhost. Root is not set properly, it should be set to `dist/browser`. Also, `Internal server error` is the the default apache error page. If you want help, you need to look at the logs and indicate the real error...

Comment: @David - thank you for your involvement. I edited the post with vhost file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am using Let’s Encrypt CA, it creates its .conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

> yourdomain-le-ssl.conf

So proxing to localhost:4000 from `yourdomain.conf` file was not the right configuration, proxing from `yourdomain-le-ssl.conf` is correct